# Batch file to compare text files with no headers for duplicates

Tags: batch-file, text, header, duplicates

I need to create a batch file that will do the following: I have 2 text files with no headers that I need to compare with one another for duplicates in one certain column.

File 1 looks like:

```
34551897        455684           2170865488
34668571        455674           2165586244
34156474        456178           2156189465
34156184        428516           2153185687
```

File 2 looks like:

```
3415647         458566           2183154897
3515647         168594           2156984161
3513157         412348           2156748416
3581354         154613           2156789131
```

I need to compare the second columns from file 1 to file 2 for duplicates, and if there is a duplicate, return a zero. Else, return a 1.

The text files are located on the same machine, but different folders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a few questions to clarify some things (I'm a bit slow you see)... Does the duplicate need to be in exactly the same position in the second column for both files? When you say `return a zero. Else, return a 1.` do you mean literally output a `1` or `0` in the command prompt window? or simply confirm that a duplicate exists or not?

Comment: [help/on-topic]: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._ Hint: pay your attention to `ECHO`, `SET`, `FOR /F`, `IF` and `EXIT` commands in [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/). Return here and [edit] your question to ask more help with possible difficulties.

Comment: @JosefZ I have noticed quite a few questions on this community for help, whereby the asker specifies what's required, but no evidence of an attempt at doing it, or even a potential route they may be thinking about, is given. I only assume the asker is asking for the answer so that they may reverse-learn by it... or "learn by comparison" as some say... regardless I benefit from these questions, since I relish the challenge and enjoy finding the solution, but this defeats the true purpose; that the asker actually learns from my effort too, and not just conveniently using it as a means to an end.

Comment: @chris Thanks for your help Chris. Your batch worked perfectly. I'm new to creating batch files and was having some troubles with the findstr command. I was able to use what you provided, along with some additional scripting to get my job to work. I learned a lot from this. Thanks again!

Comment: @Brandon... no problem, all the best! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help, if the position of a matching string is irrelevant:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0

for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=TAB " %%i in ("C:\TEST\test columns 1.txt") do (
echo %%i
)>>C:\TEST\temp.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=TAB " %%i in ("C:\TEST\test columns 2.txt") do (
findstr /c:"%%i" "C:\TEST\temp.txt"
if !errorlevel!==0 set /a count+=1
)
echo !count! match(es)
pause
del /q "C:\TEST\temp.txt"
```

You will need to replace the paths with the ones relevant to you. Furthermore you can do it more efficiently by **nesting** the `for` conditions:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0

for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=TAB " %%i in ("C:\TEST\test columns 1.txt") do (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=TAB " %%j in ("C:\TEST\test columns 2.txt") do (   
    if %%i==%%j set /a count+=1
    )
)
echo !count! match(es)
pause
```

Comment: If I wanted to exit with a 0 return if the count was greater than 0, or exit with a 1 if the count was = 0 would it look something like:

echo %count% > 0 
exit 0

echo %count% == 0
exit 1

Comment: Put in in an `if` statement, also batch uses `errorlevels` see [exit](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) so you need to use `/b`... and if you're wanting to run a second batch based on how the first one terminates you may need a [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) command. Good luck!